# Pickling Pandas DataFrames subclasses which include metadata

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pickle

The question about attaching metadata to Pandas objects, and getting that data to survive a pickle/unpickle process is a perennial one.  I see some very old answers, which basically say that you can't.  Hopefully, a more current answer to this question will be yes.  I'm using Pandas 0.23.3.

I've made some Pandas DataFrame subclasses.  I think I know how to do this correctly.  I have a `_constructor` method, and my `__init__` method can handle `BlockManager` objects.  When I create meta-data attributes, I suppress the UserWarning which cautions that I'm not creating a column in the DataFrame itself, which in my case is fine.

When I want to save the DataFrame to disk, I call `my_fancy_df.to_pickle(file_path)`.  When I want to reload it, I use `my_fancy_df = pandas.read_pickle(file_path)`.  **MY** meta-data gets removed.  Pandas itself has meta-data which pickles and unpickles fine, such as the `DataFrame.name` attribute.  I would like to copy this behavior for my attributes.

I could intercept the `.to_pickle` call in my subclass, and arrange to write the meta-data separately into the same file object.  But I don't see an equivalent approach for changing the way that data is reloaded.  The read_pickle function is general-purpose, and lives in the Pandas namespace, it doesn't belong to the DataFrame class.

I could possibly write a custom unpickling function, external to my class and use that... it seems clumsy.  If there's an elegant way to get this job done, I haven't found it.

I'm also not dead-set on using pickle.  If HDF5 is more suitable, for example, I can switch.  I do need to pickle arbitrary Python data types in the DataFrame, though.  The content in the cells is not just strings and numbers, I have tuples as well, and in one subclass I've built I even placed DataFrames inside DataFrames.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Interestingly, it seems another user asked [a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57237664/) just an hour before you.

Comment: Following up to myself: my self-defined meta-data doesn't even survive a SLICE operation, so maybe I should understand that first.  It looks like I might need to do more than just a `super().__init__(arg[0])` in my `__init__` when a BlockManager is passed.  Saving and restoring to disk may be a related problem,

Comment: Yes, @MichaelKolber, that is interesting.  There's a clear interest in having this capability.

Comment: See the docs on [subclassing pandas data structures](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures), and in particular the section on [defining original properties](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#define-original-properties).

Comment: Thanks @root, it looks like a few things have in fact changed since the last time I looked at the Pandas subclassing docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment from [user "root"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3339965/root) was helpful.  I have confirmed that if you define a class property called _metadata inside your custom DataFrame subclass, it is the list of the instance properties you want to retain through slicing, pickling, and unpickling operations.