# Auxiliary data / description in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Imagine I have pd.DataFrame containing a lot of rows and I want to add some string data describing/summarizing it.

1. One way to do this would be to add column with this value, but it would be a complete waste of memory (e.g. when the string would be a long specification of ML model).
2. I could also insert it in file name - but this has limitations and is very impractical at saving/loading.
3. I could store this data in separate file, but it is not what I want.
4. I could make a class based on pd.DataFrame and add this field, but then I am unsure if save/load pickle would still work properly.

So is there some real clean way to store something like "description" in pandas DataFrame? Preferentially such that would withstand to_pickle/read_pickle operations.

[EDIT]: Ofc, this generates next questions such as what if we concatenate dataframes with such informations? But let's stick to saving/loading problem only.

Comment: Just a thought - if you make a class based on pd.DataFrame and then pickle it - you can always just load the pickle itself. Pickle completely stores the object itself so you shall be fine

Comment: Other thought - you can always make a pandas dictionary with just two items - name of dataframe and dataframe itself.

Answer (score 0):

Googled it a bit, you can name a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame( data=np.ones([10,10]) )
df.name = 'My name'

print(df.name)
```

Comment: This is cool but:
q = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1, 'b':2},{'a':3, 'b':4}])   
q.name = 'my_name'   
q.to_pickle('test.pkl')   
w = pd.read_pickle('test.pkl')   
print(w.name)   
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @RunTheGauntlet Interesting, apparently Pandas has some odd things happening with pickling \ depickling and even slicing them (so it kills metadata in such cases): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57237664/cant-unpickle-class-that-inherits-from-pandas-dataframe

People suggest you try dill instead of pickle